# Bypass nginx ingress controller rate limit

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm trying to enable some sort of rate limiting for a EKS cluster using nginx ingress controller where I also need to somehow whitelist a couple if IPs from this rate limit rule that are in charge of health and metrics checkups.
If I use the annotations `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections` it just adds  the limit to the whitelist IPs.
Is there another way to setup this?
Thank you!

Comment: hi. just to understand full picture. Are you looking solution only for nginx ingress controller? or you need resolve task no matter what ingress to use?

Comment: Hello, I need to solve this using nginx ingress controller. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in fact that it ignores the whitelisting due to the lack of `x-forwarded-for`, but this activating this in production can be a security flaw, as discussed on: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/2881